# How do I properly initiate the ".getFilter"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am to perform a filter function. I want to set an array as a variable in one of my google sheets and automate a filter using dates. I have tried to input the following code:

```
var filteredData = sheet3.getFilter(function(row)
{var date = row[1]; return date >= beginDate_quarter && date <= endDate_quarter});
```

However, I get an error message stating:

> Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getFilter.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, the getFilter method of Class Sheet has no arguments. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) So, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the details of your question?

Comment: I was able to get a permissive for the filter function, however, I ran into another problem. I want to place a dataRange of values from one sheet to another but I run into another error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.